# How can I create a class instance from a string in TypeScript (similar to .constantize.new in rails)?

Tags: typescript

In Rails, I can take a string name of a class and do `someclass.constantize.new`

If I have a string, `const classString = 'User'`, is it possible for me to create an instance of a `User` from it?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
const classMap = {
  'User': User,
   // OtherClass ...
}

const user = new classMap[classString]
```

2.

```
const classes = [User /*, OtherClass ... */];
const user = new (classes.find(c => c.name === classString))
```

3. `eval` - but it's not recommended.